# NServiceBus UseTransport not working after upgrading to .NET 6

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, nservicebus, .net-6.0

I'm using NserviceBus with the Azure Function project ( `NServiceBus.AzureFunctions.InProcess.ServiceBus`). Application is using azure service bus as the transport and it is configured in function startup by using the below code

```
 var transport = configuration.AdvancedConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
            transport.ConnectionString(@"AzureWebJobsServiceBus".GetConfig());
```

Everything was working fine in .NET Core 3.1 and Azure function version 3.0. Recently I upgrade the project to .NET 6 and Function version to 4.0. After the upgrade, `functionEndpoint.Process` is throwing a null reference exception.

If the `UseTransport` code is commented out in function startup, no exception is thrown and the messages are getting processed successfully. But I need to have the `UseTransport` in the startup configuration for the NServiceBus to set up the transport topology automatically. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What is the version of `Nuget Package: NServiceBus.Transport.AzureServiceBus` you're using in the project?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Using the latest stable version v2.0.2

Comment: What is the `NServiceBus` version you're using?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT 7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the NServiceBus.AzureFunctions.InProcess.ServiceBus package then you should not be calling `UseTransport<>()`.

The library does this for you but it also contains some additional code to prevent the message receiver part of the transport from starting. Instead, the endpoint simply sits and waits for one of the Azure Function Trigger methods to call one of the endpoints Process methods.

If you call `UseTransport<>()` yourself, then the standard message receiver is started and when the Azure Function Trigger calls a Process method, the interception code has not been properly configured. That is why you see a Null Reference Exception.

You should not rely on the NServiceBus endpoint to create the topology in the transport. The endpoint is only created when the first Azure function is triggered. Typically this happens when a message arrives but that can't happen before the topology is set up. There is a [command-line tool](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/azure-functions-service-bus/#preparing-the-azure-service-bus-namespace) that is provided to help provision a new Azure Service Bus environment for use with NServiceBus.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the stable versions for your application like:

[image]

I would suggest to change the syntax and try based on connection string use cases:

**To use Azure Service Bus as the underlying transport:**
**Method 1:**

If your connection string variable `AzureServiceBusConnectionString` is present in the web config file, then try calling the connection string using the below code:

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>();
var connectionString = context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBusConnectionString"); 
transport.ConnectionString(connectionString);
```

**Method 2: Giving the connection string directly**

```
var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<AzureServiceBusTransport>(); transport.ConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://[NAMESPACE].servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=[KEYNAME];SharedAccessKey=[KEY]");
```

For more detailed information to fetch the connection string from web config using configuration manager to context in the application (method 1), please check this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/build-message-driven-apps-nservicebus?tabs=Sender#set-up-the-sender).